# C++ Abstract Base Template Class Non-Void Method

Tags: c++, templates, pure-virtual

I have an abstract base template class that contains members functions, some that are void, others returning data types ranging from primitive data types to the template parameter data type. I am still new to C++, and I know that I don't necessarily have to implement the pure virtual functions in the base class unless I wish to call them in the derived classes. This idea was fine for member functions that had no return value. For a function that returned an integer, I returned a 0. But when I got to a function that returned a reference to T, the template parameter, I did not know what to do. I tried the two following returns.

```
template <typename T>
T& AbstractBaseClass<T>::function(){
return T();
}
```

and

```
template <typename T>
T& AbstractBaseClass<T>::function(){
return T& tmp= T();
}
```

But neither seem to work, and I cannot not define these functions because I get an undefined reference error for the functions. I assume this error is because the functions are templates. What is the appropriate way to implement a non-void pure virtual function?

```
template <typename T>
class AbstractBaseClass{
public:
virtual ~AbstractBaseClass() = 0;
T& function();
}

template <typename T>
T& AbstractBaseClass<T>::function(){
    //what must I do here when I don't have any member variable
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you try to return a reference to a *temporary* object. Think about what happens when that temporary object is destructed (which is immediately), what will the reference be referencing then?

Comment: Would I have to try something like "return T& tmp= new T()"? I am still not quite sure about providing implementations for a pure virtual function, especially when the method is non-void.

Comment: Do you *have* to return a reference? Why? Why can't you return by value? And this has nothing to do with virtual functions. Also, a "pure" virtual function is one that has no body or implementation or definition. It would be declared such as `virtual someReturnType function(possibleArguments) = 0;` Note the `= 0` at the end, that is what makes a function a pure virtual or abstract function.

Comment: The problem statement is as such, returning a reference to T, which is what boggles me as well. Naturally, I would think to have a return type of T and return T(). Is there no way to return a reference?

Comment: @n.m. For a pure virtual function, is it necessary to add "virtual" and/or "=0" to the function signature in the source file?

Comment: @Skipher You can return a reference if it's not a reference to a temporary.  `T()` creates a temporary object that doesn't exist after the return.

Comment: Yes there is a way to return a reference, but it has to be a reference to an object who doesn't gets destructed at once. The objects lifetime must exceed the lifetime of the reference to it. Perhaps you should return a reference to a member variable instead? Without knowing what problem you're actually trying to solve, we can't help you more than just guessing wildly. The problem is *not* "how to return a reference", that's *a* solution. The problem is what made you come up with your solution to begin with. Please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: We'd have to see the actual code, but they must be expecting you to have a member variable in a class. Then you return the member variable. That has the same lifetime as the object so it exists even after the call to the function.

Comment: The abstract base class does not have any member variable, and I have considered possible ways to return a reference to an object, as I also understand that I cannot return the reference to a local variable, which will go out of scope upon exiting the function. However, my other question is, does the function header in the source file for a pure virtual function require "=0"? I understand that I cannot add "virtual" because this is a template function.

Comment: The abstract base class might not have a member variable, but your concrete derived class definitely needs one.

Comment: @MillieSmith Certainly, but the base class cannot see any new member variable in the derived class, which did not exist in the base class though. How can this help me?

Comment: It is necessary to have both `virtual` and `=0` *inside the class definition*, normally in a header file. A pure virtual function doesn't need a body.

Comment: Like I said, a pure abstract function doesn't have an implementation. It's an *interface* only. It's the child-classes that implements the function, and there you have member variables that you can return references to.

Comment: The base class cannot see any new member variable in the derived class, which is perfectly OK. It doesn't need to.

Comment: However, as I mentioned in the question, I get an "undefined reference" error when I don't provide an implementation, though it may be empty, and I suspect that this is because the abstract base class and the methods are templatized

Comment: Your base class has a pure virtual function. All derived classes that you want to actually create objects of need to implement that function. How they implement that function is up to them. The derived classes even get to use their member variables when they implement those functions. Thus, they also get to return those member variables.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. Like not making the function an *abstract* function. For an abstract function you need *both* `virtual` *and* `= 0`, when you declare the function in the base class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Therefore, my function header in the source file should be "virtual T& AbstractBaseClass<T>::function()=0"? I am unable to do so because I get an error saying "templates may not be 'virtual'"

Comment: You cannot write `AbstractBaseClass<T>::` inside the definition of ``AbstractBaseClass`. You must write just `virtual T& function()=0`. You cannot write `=0` outside of said definition.

Comment: Sigh. The answer to "what must I do here when I don't have any member variable" is return a local static variable, return a global variable, or pretty much, you can't. Read up on rvalues, lvalues, temporaries, and references.

Comment: Delete the entire `template <typename T> T& AbstractBaseClass<T>::function(){}` part, you don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a pure virtual function and a derived class that implements it (some member functions omitted for clarity):

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
   public:
     virtual T& get() = 0;
     virtual ~Base() = 0;
};

template <class T>
Base<T>::~Base() {}

template <class T>
class Derived: public Base<T>
{
   T t;
   public:
     T& get() override { return t; }
};
```

Note how `get()` in `Base` has no implementation, and the implementation of `get` in `Derived` uses a new data member not available in `Base`.

Note also that a pure virtual *destructor*, unlike other pure virtual functions, **must** have an implementation. Normally one doesn't need a pure virtual destructor if there are other pure functions in the class though. It is shown here for illustration.

Comment: Suppose get() was neither a pure virtual or a virtual function and that it needed to provide an implementation. How would a base class implementation of get() return a reference to T without the existence of member variables in class Base?

Comment: @Skipher Such functions cannot be defined, which is OK because it makes no sense for them to be defined.

Comment: @Skipher It wouldn't. If it's not a virtual function, then it has an implementation in the base class. To return a reference in the base class, it needs a member variable in the base class (or a global variable, or something that isn't temporary).

Comment: @n.m.but it appears that I must define it because the compiler tells me "no return statement in function returning non-void".

Comment: @Skipher can you post your code? That would make it a lot easier to help you. But just to be clear, you have to return *something*. You cannot have an empty implementation `{}` for a function that is supposed to return something.

Comment: @Skipher. Let's try again. If you need a function that derived classes will implement, make it pure virtual and don't provide an implementation in the base class. If you want to implement a function in the base class, **it must have sense in the context of the base class alone** regardless of any derived classes. What should your base class function **do**? If you cannot explain it, the function has no reason to exist.